# Are there any wearable IP cameras?

Tags: live-recording

I'm trying to find a wearable camera (to mount on a helmet, or on the shoulder) that support live-streaming video over a WiFi-network or the mobile phone network (HSPA or LTE) to a custom video streaming server. Are there any such cameras that you know of?

I have considered using something like a GoPro HD Hero 2 with an Eye-Fi SD-card. That I believe would make it possible to upload the video to an FTP-server, and then I could provide on-demand streaming of the files that are uploaded. However, it would be really nice to allow live-streaming, and in that case the FTP-server setup wouldn't be a good option.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Contour cameras, with a small transmitter-box connected to the camera. If you want decent quality footage, you should avoid cameras with built-in wireless streaming, as most really do not have the capability to transmit in full quality.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What are you referring to when you say "decent quality footage"? My purpose doesn't necessarily require HD or even close to, it's not for video production. Do you know any wearable cameras with built-in wireless streaming, that I could check out?

Comment: What I mean by decent quality footage, is that the typical cameras with built-in wifi, will compress the footage quite heavily in order to amount of data needed to be transferred down to a minimum. This means either a lot of graining or the loss of resolution - sometimes both.

Comment: If you want decent streaming in an affordable pricerange the Contour+ hooks up nicely with the Cerevo's LiveShell ($300), and I believe that GoPro has a similar solution (Wifi BacPac) planned for fall 2012, although it's rumored that the wifi is quite sluggish and will cause lags and glitches when going with 720p or above.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way would be to get a small camera with HDMI output (like say, a [GoPro HD Hero 2](http://gopro.com/hd-hero2-cameras/) or a [Replay XD1080](http://replayxd.com/cameras/replay-xd1080-camera/)) and hook it up to a [Livestream Broadcaster unit](http://new.livestream.com/broadcast-live/livestream-broadcaster), which looks small enough (and is battery powered) to strap on to someone.

The Livestream Broadcaster supports wi-fi, or even plugging a USB modem directly into it. There's also the [Teradeck](http://teradek.com) stuff if the Livestream Broadcaster doesn't do it for ya.